# Google Cloud Plataform functions with error message: Cannot determine path without bucket name

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to deploy a Google Cloud Platform function using a .zip file stored in the Google Storage.

My first try was using gcloud command:

```sh
gcloud functions deploy $FUNCTION_NAME --runtime=python37 --entry-point=endpoint --stage-bucket=my_bucket --memory=128MB --set-env-vars=var1=value1,var2=value2 --project=$GCP_PROJECT_ID --trigger-http
```

Then, I get the following error message:

```
....................................failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Function failed on loading user code. Error message: Cannot determine path without bucket name.
```

Also I tried to use the Google Cloud Platform web interface to deploy my function. I tried both `Source code` options `Zip upload` and `Zip from cloud storage`, but still getting the same error.

[image]

PS.: when using the `gcloud` command the files is zipped and uploaded successfully to the storage and the function created, but the function is with the error above.

Comment: In the first gcloud command in your post, might you have meant --source as opposed to --stage-bucket?

Comment: @Kolban --source must point to a local folder where the function's code is. Also getting the same error. I'm assuming this might be some bug on the platform because I get the same error using the web console.

Comment: I think the issue is related to the file structure you have. Have you tried deploying code samples provided by the official guides? I believe we might be facing a bad error message issue here, so if you could share more information about what you are trying to deploy, it will be easier for others to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @pessolato based on your comment and marian.vladoi 's test I figured out the problem. I'm closing the issue with my findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my `main.py` I have the following code:

```py
(...)

STORAGE_BUCKET = os.environ.get('STORAGE_BUCKET')
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(STORAGE_BUCKET)

(...)
```

But I forgot to set the **STORAGE_BUCKET** variable in the `--set-env-vars=`.

So the error message it was regarding the `storage_client.get_bucket(STORAGE_BUCKET)` and not to the deploy itself.

The error message should be more meaningful pointing to a error in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your use case, and it worked as expected for me:

1. I followed the tutorial [Quickstart: Using the gcloud Command-Line Tool](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/quickstart)
2. I zip the files: `main.py` and `requirements.txt`:

   ```
   zip code.zip main.py requirements
   ```
3. I copied the zip file to my bucket:

   ```
   gsutil cp code.zip gs://mybucket/
   ```
4. I deployed the cloud function:

   ```
   gcloud functions deploy funczip --runtime=python37 --entry-point=hello_get --stage-bucket=mybucket --memory=128MB --set-env-vars=var1=World --project=myproject --trigger-http
   ```
5. I tested the function:

   ```
   curl  https://us-central1-myproject.cloudfunctions.net/funczip
   ```
6. Output:

   ```
   Hello World!
   ```